# Reference request for neural network programming in Mathematica

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request

I'm looking for a good reference/book on programming neural networks in mathematica.  I've been working through Freeman's "Simulating Neural Networks with Mathematica," but it is from 1994 so is quite dated.  Is anyone familiar with a more recent book on the subject?

For background, I'm very comfortable with pure mathematics, somewhat comfortable with general programming, and have been teaching myself to be proficient in mathematica.  I'd like to play around with implementing neural networks on mathematica for use in forecasting of high frequency economic data, so anything with a finance bent is an especially welcome reference.

Comment: Have you checked out the Neural Networks add-on package? Its pretty expensive but there might be relevant documentation or authors who could get you started. http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/neuralnetworks/

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that, but figured the documentation would be focused on specifically using the neural-nets package.  It is a good idea to go through some of the authors and see if I can find anything they've written not specifically tailored to the package.  I'm just not up for spending $900 for the add-on at this point since this is purely for my own entertainment/education.

Comment: [This blog](http://textanddatamining.blogspot.com/) deals with datamining in Mathematica. There are some nice posts about [neural nets](http://textanddatamining.blogspot.com/2011/11/buy-or-build-practical-example-to.html) as well.

Comment: Wolfram occasionally runs courses in this kind of thing: See: http://www.wolfram.com/services/education/courses/m330.html

Comment: Is the NeuralNetworks package still under development? The example here (http://library.wolfram.com/examples/exchangerate/) and the official documentation (http://media.wolfram.com/documents/NeuralNetworksDocumentation.pdf) seem to use <<LinearAlgebra`MatrixManipulation` which is obsolete!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had an interest (as one can see in my other posts) in a wide range of distributed processing and parallel computing approaches and while not seen in any of my posts machine learning approaches as well.  I looked at neural networks some years ago, and while they didn't suit the problems I worked on at the time I remembered the article Duncan and Tweney wrote as useful. A couple of others might also prove useful.

Three references follow:

**AI AND STATISTICAL APPLICATIONS
Mathematica: A flexible design environment for neural networks**

From the Journal:
Behavior Research Methods, Instruments, & Computers 1997,29 (2). 194-199

https://doi.org/10.3758/BF03204810

From 1997, a few years more recent than Freeman's.

Freely available as a pdf [article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03204810.pdf):

> Abstract:
>
> Several neural networks were developed in *Mathematica* in order to
> explore the role of "spiky" neurons in neural network memory
> simulations. Using *Mathematica* for this task confirmed its value as a
> powerful tool for neural network development: It exhibited distinct
> advantages over other environments in programming ease, flexibility
> of data structures, and the graphical assessment of network
> performance.

One of its authors: Sean C. Duncan has moved from Bowling Green University to Miami University.  He has a website: https://se4n.org/

Its other author: Ryan Tweney remains at Bowling Green University and has his own website: [http://personal.bgsu.edu/~tweney/](http://personal.bgsu.edu/%7Etweney/) (Update: Ryan Tweney passed away in 2020; an archived snapshot of his website is available in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190904023851/http://personal.bgsu.edu/%7Etweney/).)

You can find contact information for each of them on their respective websites.  I've always found academics generous with what they know.  The article or contacting them might lead you to better sources of information on this.

**Mathematica Neural Networks package**.

You can download the pdf of the manual for the [Mathematica Neural Networks package](http://media.wolfram.com/documents/NeuralNetworksDocumentation.pdf).  Pretty extensive, indeed.

**The Power of Neural Networks**

A review in which Brian Cogan briefly assesses NeuroSolutions from NeuroDimension, and Neural Networks, a Mathematica add-on, from Scientific Computing World March/April 2003

http://www.neurosolutions.com/resources/scw.pdf

Answer (score 7):

***NOTE: info in the 2012 answer by @Jagra is outdated. This is rapidly developing science and technology.***

---

Etienne Bernard, who was the head of machine learning group at Wolfram, recently published a general book on machine learning with Wolfram Language. Chapter 11 "Deep Learning Methods" (**108 pages...**) does neural nets from scratch. You can check this PDF sample where the beginning of chapter 11 is present https://t.co/pbYh0wJH0S.

COMPLETE BOOK:

- [Wolfram page](https://www.wolfram-media.com/products/introduction-to-machine-learning.html)
- [Announcement by the author & Complete 3rd chapter](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2469295) (*you can comment and communicated with Etienne Bernard there*)

Other substential resources:

- [Book in Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksOverview.html)
- [Wolfram-U (university) has plenty of free courses](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/machine-learning)

[image]