# Resources to learn about Neural Nets using Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, education, reference-request

I'm interested in learning about Neural Nets and I'd really like my instruction to be in Mathematica if possible.

For instance, a tutorial like this one: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html but using Mathematica instead of Python would be amazing. Does such a resource exist right now?

Comment: Is [Reference request for neural network programming in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/reference-request-for-neural-network-programming-in-mathematica) of some help?

Comment: It's all pretty dated so I'd rather not use those references, but if nothing else is available I'll look into them.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question. But I wanted to add that personally, I find that I learn the most from following a tutorial in another language and being forced to do all the translations to my target language. This is especially true if you already know the target language well.

Comment: 3 years and 3 months, 211 views, and still no answer :) That shows how much meaningful tutorials are lacking. Mason, in my opinion, the best way to understand how NNs are handled in M is by first recognizing that in M the MXNet system is used under the hood. Basically, it's wrappers to manage MXNet with M code. That is illustrated very well in webinars from Markus von Almsick. Although they are limited to image applications, they give you a good overview over handling the different layers in a MXNet-like fashion. For example https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?p=14&disp=grid&v=2409.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was posted many things have changed with Neural Networks. Please see the following key references below.

- [Neural Networks in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksOverview.html) - This is a main collection oof tutorials on almost all the basics you can do with Neural Network framework in the Wolfram Language
- [Neural Networks Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html) - This is a collection of all functions relevant Neural Network and as usual every function page is a tutorial-like guide with many examples.
- [Wolfram Neural Net Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/) - The Wolfram Neural Net Repository is a public resource that hosts an expanding collection of trained and untrained neural network models, suitable for immediate evaluation, training, visualization, transfer learning and more. Each net has a doc page dedicated to it with examples.
- [Machine Learning at Wolfram U](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/machine-learning/) - Extensive video courses and tutorials.
- [Q&A Mathematica v.11 Neural Networks: A comprehensive look at Layers, Net Functions, and pioneering into this [[experimental]] code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124977) - This is something that users of this forum started doing to comprehend growing Neural Networks functionality.

Comment: no, the o/p is asking for a *tutorial* :)

Answer (score 3):

This video recording:

- [ORLMLDS Deep learning series (2): "Using Keras with R (...and MXNet with WL)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AidENXetn3o)

uses both R and Mathematica (WL). It should be a good introduction to the typical functionalities provided by Neural Network libraries, and related rules of thumb and techniques.

There is a dedicated GitHub repository: [MathematicaVsR -- Deep Learning Examples](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaVsR/tree/master/Projects/DeepLearningExamples).